# How to stop linux watchdog feeding?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm making a daemon that feeds the watchdog (by writing to `/dev/watchdog`), but when the code stops writing, I expected the machine to reboot, but it didn't.

I though that maybe something else is feeding the watchdog.
I see that `/sys/class/watchdog/watchdog0/timeleft` is reaching zero and then starts from 30 again
I also see a running `watchdogd` kernel thread that might be feeding it.

`sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /dev/watchdog"` returns `bash: /dev/watchdog: Device or resource busy`

`sudo fuser /dev/watchdog` returned nothing however.

how do I stop feeding the watchdog and trigger reboot?

if that matters, the code is running inside a VM

Comment: Per https://linuxhint.com/linux-kernel-watchdog-explained/ you should use `cat >> /dev/watchdog` then press enter twice to test it. There is some implication that it counting is normal and a sign of perfect operation, you need to actually *halt* it in order to trigger a reset. There is also a suggestion that the correct watchdog for your system (VM) needs to be loaded as well.

Comment: `sudo bash -c "cat >> /dev/watchdog"` also returns `bash: /dev/watchdog: Device or resource busy`.


As for "you need to actually halt it in order to trigger a reset" -
halt what?